# Is there a way to allow "read only" access to settings in environments where 'allowAdminChanges' => false?

Tags: admin, settings, projectconfig

Is there a way to allow "read only" access to settings in environments where `'allowAdminChanges' => false`?

Project Config is a great convenience and I understand why we need to set `'allowAdminChanges' => false` in some (ie, non-dev) environments. But it is fairly inconvenient not to be able to at least *inspect* settings in other environments.

In some cases, sure, you can check if fields show up, etc. But for some deeper settings it's much trickier to verify that the setting was correctly applied via project config syncing when you can not directly inspect the setting itself.

I'd love to be able to view pages in `/admin/settings` in production for example, while not being able to make any *actual* changes when `'allowAdminChanges' => false`. **Is there no way to enable just a "read only" mode for settings? Or is setting `'allowAdminChanges' => true` the only way to be able to view settings?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the entire project config data from **Utilities** → **Project Config**, which should contain whatever values you’re looking for.

You can find a related discussion at [craftcms/cms#4371](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4371).